# Does HDMI output work on the L502X?

Tags: laptop, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get HDMI output working on a Dell XPS 15 L502x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61144/how-do-i-get-hdmi-output-working-on-a-dell-xps-15-l502x)

I would like to add a monitor to my XPS 15 L502X but when I connect a monitor using HDMI Ubuntu 11.10 does not recognise and I cannot extend my display on to that monitor.

There are [past questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61144/how-do-i-get-hdmi-output-working-on-a-dell-xps-15-l502x) which tend to conclude that this is not possible but they are rather old, I have found some rumblings on the internet that this is now possible but no specific details.

Is it now possible to get HDMI output working on my L502X?

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that it *should* work. When something that should work doesn't, then the right thing to do, is to file a bug on Launchpad.net.