# Ubuntu 12.04. How to set up dual monitor with Intel 2nd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, dell, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have a Dell XPS15 l502x dual-booting Win8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

When I try to connect my second monitor through the HDMI port, the second monitor just says there's no signal.

When I run `lspci -v`, I get the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 04b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

When I run `xrandr`, I get:

`Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0

   1024x768       60.0

   800x600        60.3     56.2

   640x480        59.9

   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

`HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

`DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

I have no clue how to enable my second monitor. I do have another NVIDIA graphics card:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f`

in my laptop but I don't want to use it since the support for NVIDIA Optimus graphics cards is poor on Linux.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?
Thanks!

Comment: **Node** was right. In xps15 l502x Ubuntu activates the Intel graphics card by default. To make use of the NVIDIA card, we have to install the bumblebee project.
 
Link: http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/dell-xps-15-l502x-ubuntu-linux/

Quote from the blog:

> Graphics

>Upon installation only the integrated graphics card is active (Intel HD 3000).
To enable the Nvidia card, you have to install bumblebee project (Optimus Enabler for Linux). DO NOT INSTALL THE NVIDIA PROPRIETARY DRIVER manually (If you do, you won’t be able to boot); let Bumblebee installation take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Dell XPS15 l502x has an nvidia optimus chipset. Which has a real poor linux support at the moment.
I would suggest that you would use or at least try to use the "discrete graphic only" setting in bios and install the nvidia binary driver. (be careful this impacts your battery life)
Although you could try to use the latest nouveau module 1.0.9:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQyMzk

Please have a look at this question, may it helps you around your problem: [How do I get HDMI output working on a Dell XPS 15 L502x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61144/how-do-i-get-hdmi-output-working-on-a-dell-xps-15-l502x)

Comment: Well, I know that. But I mentioned in my original post that I don't want to mess with NVIDIA graphics card. Last time I installed the NVIDIA drivers it was a nightmare. I had to remove Ubuntu and install it all over again. Doesn't my current Intel integrated graphics card support dual-screen?

Comment: Afaik in your case the hdmi port is wired to the nvidia chip, so the intel chip can't see the port. https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

Comment: Aww, this is the worst case scenario :( Thanks for your input.

Comment: Nvidia Optimus + Linux is a world of pain. :/

Comment: I'll go ahead and install Bumblebee. Will see what happens...